# How to build soap request with script view?

Tags: soap, groovy, katalon-studio

I'm trying to build a SOAP request with Groovy/Java.

However, I didn't found any information on web and on Katalon documentation.

There is a lot of documentation for REST testing, but not for SOAP ...

- https://docs.katalon.com/katalon-studio/docs/create_rest_api_requests_manually.html#introduction
- https://docs.katalon.com/katalon-studio/docs/web-services-builder.html
- https://api-docs.katalon.com/

My objective is to do something like :

```
// THIS CODE IS WRONG !!!! It's just to give you an idea of my need

RequestObject requestObject = new SOAPRequestBuilder()
def variables = new HashMap<String, String>()
variables.put('variable', 'some text')
requestObject.setVariables(variables)
def response = WS.sendRequest(requestObject)
```

Someone has any idea how to do that? Thank you for help.

**Update 1**

I found this solution but I don't know if it is a best pratice ...

```
def request = findTestObject('RequestObject', [('variable') : 'some text'])
def response = WS.sendRequest(request)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for something product-agnostic, you could use [groovy-wslite](https://github.com/jwagenleitner/groovy-wslite), which handles both REST and SOAP. For example:

```
def client = new SOAPClient("http://...")
def response = client.send(SOAPAction: ...) {
    body {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, It's an external library, is it not possible to do it with Katalon internal librairies?